# Finding who a user invited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)

I'm currently able to find out who a user was invited by, by using:

```
<%= @user.invited_by.username %>
```

But i'm just not able to find the method that @user can respond to and return a list of users that particular user has invited. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this

```
 User.where(invited_by_id: @user.id)
```